# Knockout and applybindings - what is going on here?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this:

```
socket.bind('TodayTutors', function (data) {
            tuts.push(data);
            ko.applyBindings(tuts);
        });
```

Now, this bind receives some data every 30 seconds. Then I am pushing this data to an observable array, and I want this data to be rendered. Now, this does not work, but why? If I put a breakpoint right before `ko.applyBindings(tuts);` the `data` is rendered, and then when I let the breakpoint free, this render is removed. So I tried something like this, hoping that .push() will automatically update my views:

```
ko.applyBindings(tuts);
socket.bind('TodayTutors', function (data) {
                tuts.push(data);
            });
```

But this doesn't want to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post some more of your code. Like what is tuts? and what does your view look like?

Comment: Can you put together a test case in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `ko.applyBindings();` is somehow manipulating the flow of an application, I solved my problem by doing this:

```
{
   ko.applyBindings(tuts);
}
socket.bind('TodayTutors', function (data) {
                tuts.push(data);
            });
```